# Force the inside td not to behave like tr

Tags: html, css, styles

I have a `tr` with `opacity: 0.1`, the `td` inside of it naturally will respect this `opacity` and will be transparent.
I wanted to know if there is a way to force the `td` not to respect the style of `tr` and have `opacity: 1.0`.

```css
tr {
  background: #e56a54;
  width: 100px;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
td {
  opacity: 1.0;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      reshad
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/orww77b3/1/)

Comment: No, the `td` is a child of the `tr`, changing the opacity of the row will affect the cell as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way is to apply opacity to the background of the TR and leave the TD.

From W3schools:

> When using the opacity property to add transparency to the background
>   of an element, all of its child elements become transparent as well.
>   This can make the text inside a fully transparent element hard to
>   read. If you do not want to apply opacity to child elements, use RGBA
>   color values instead (See "More Examples" below).
>   http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp

```css
tr {
  background: rgba(229, 106, 84, 0.1);
  width: 100px;
}
td {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      reshad
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't want to use rgba. Does this solution work with hex code as well?

Comment: @reshad No, but there are tons of hex to rgb converters. Just find one in Google as I just did to translate your hex code. CSS preprocessors have functions that can, but I don't think you should use them just for that.

Comment: Why don't you use rgba? @reshad .... you can get the values in 1 sec, with chrome developer tools or illustrator or any of the thousand web pages to convert.

Answer (score 0):

No. `td` is a child of `tr` so if `tr` is transparent, so will be all of its content. (There's obviously no property like `opacity: 2` to overcome initial opacity of the child).

You want to make the background transparent, or use transparent overlay with `position: absolute; z-index: 1` that will stay over all contents of `tr`, and add `z-index: 2` to `td`.